# NoReverseMatch Django URL

Tags: django, django-templates

Currently suffering with a NoReverseMatch error with Django URL tag.
Been following The definitive guide to Django, the Django doucmentation and searched around here and the internet

urls:

```
url(r'^test/', Search_Page),
url(r'^search/', Search),
url(r'^details/', Details_Main),
url(r'^Link/(d+)/$', Link),
url(r'^$', 'Parks.views.Link', name="home"),
url(r'^(?P<result_name>)/$', Link),
```

ViewS:

```
def Link(request, result_name):
    return render_to_response('Search_Page.html')
```

template:

```
{% for result in results %}
    <a href="{% url name result.name %}">test</a>
```

Error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /search/
Reverse for 'name' with arguments '(u'North West Thrill Centre',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.Request Method: GET 
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?search=a&type=parks&submit=Search 
Django Version: 1.4.2 
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch 
Exception Value: Reverse for 'name' with arguments '(u'North West Thrill Centre',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render, line 424 
Python Executable: C:\Python27\python.exe 
Python Version: 2.7.3 
Python Path: ['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Django\\ParkManager',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages'] 
Server time: Mon, 4 Feb 2013 16:44:27 +0000 

Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\User\Documents\Django\ParkManager\Templates\Details_Main.html, error at line 23
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What view are you attempting to call? You are calling the URL on the `name` view, but the `name` does not exist. Since you only have one named view, `home`, I'll assume that's the view you are trying to use.

Neither your view nor your URLs takes an argument, yet you are passing `result.name` as an argument in the URL.

You need to either accept a parameter in your view via `def Link(request, result_name):` and capture it in your URL via a regex with `(?P<result_name>..`, or call your URL without the passed parameter:

```
{% for result in results %}
    <a href="{% url home %}">test</a>
```

Since you have no logic in your views yet, and are passing a multi-word parameter and not "slugifying" it - I'm going to assume you want to do the latter and just remove the parameter from your URL call.

Comment: when I remove the later part the url goes straight to 127.0.0.1/8000 (without out anything ending)

Updated the post to match my revised code...still noluck

Comment: You are passing the URL to the `name` view. The URL for this view is `127.0.0.1/8000`, so it is doing just as you are asking it to. The new URL you've added is incorrect. It needs a `regex` after `(?P<result_name>)` to catch the variable that you are passing, but you are passing a multi-word variable and this needs to be combined - that is called a `slug`. Have you checked out the Django tutorial? I highly suggest you check that out as a first step. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I had read through the documentation regaridng URL tags but it didn't help.However, after looking at your answer again, it worked for me
code now reads: <a href="/results/{{ result.id }} ">test</a>

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Your {% url name result.name %} is the problem.

Since your Link method has a keyword argument, your url reverse template tag should have a matching keyword argument.

### template.html

```
<a href="{% url search result_name=result.name %}">test</a>
```

Continued reading to make it clear what the problem is, as you have set it up now, the proper way to reverse a url in a template would be this:
    {% url [name] [args] [kwargs] %}

where,
  [name] is one of the following: test, search_start, details, link, home, or search. Or a full path to the view function but I would recommend keeping it simple for now.
  [args] can be empty, or a argument list.
  [kwargs] can be empty, or a keyword argument list.

The docs on the url tag can be found here and outline other ways to use it (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url).

***As an aside, you are going to run into problems with characters that are not allowed in urls that are allowed in your search string like spaces and ampersands.**

### urls.py

```
url(r'^test/', Search_Page, name="test"),
url(r'^search/', Search, name="search_start"),
url(r'^details/', Details_Main, name="details"),
url(r'^Link/(d+)/$', Link, name="link"),
url(r'^$', 'Parks.views.Link', name="home"),
url(r'^(?P<result_name>)/$', Link, name="search"),
```

### another_template.html

```
<a href="{% url search result_name=result.name %}">test</a>
<!-- and more examples -->
<a href="{% url test %}">link to test</a>  
<a href="{% url search_start %}">link to search</a> 
<a href="{% url details %}">link to details</a> 
{% for a_link in links %}
    <a href="{% url link a_link.id %}">link to details (of a_link)</a> 
{% endfor %}
<a href="{% url home %}">home</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.
Unfortunatley it didn't work. However, I read through the online documentation and found a way to get my desired result without the url tag.
My template now reads: <a href="/results/{{result.id}}">test</a>
and that seems to work fine

Comment: It is not proper form to create urls in this way (Violated DRY principle in a subtle way). I would suggest getting the url reverser to work to appease the django gods. What is the error when using {% url link a_link.id %}?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether that field exists in model.
If field exists, check for spelling whether it is same as in model